# How to copy inspector edit text value inside element box in jointJS - Rappid

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, jointjs, rappid

I want when writing something on the inspector displayName edit text to pass it to the inbox name of every element.[image]

My javascript code is the following:

```
  var count = 0;
//Code to edit element inboxName with value given from displayName field
                cell.on('change:wi_displayName', function(cell, change, opt) {

                    if(count == 0){
                    //Do nothing the 1st time
                    }
                    else {
                        var inboxName = cell.get('wi_displayName');
                        cell.set( cell.attr('text/text'), inboxName);

                    }
                    count++;

                })
//End of code to edit element inboxName with value given from displayName field
```

but the problem is in the final line:

```
cell.set( cell.attr('text/text'), inboxName);
```

**How should I set the value?**

My stencil json for this element is :

```
new joint.shapes.basic.Circle({
            size: { width: 5, height: 3 },
            attrs: {
                circle: { width: 50, height: 30, fill: '#000000' },
                text: { text: 'START', fill: '#ffffff', 'font-size': 10, stroke: '#000000', 'stroke-width': 0 }
            }
        })
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the text attribute on your `basic.Circle` element with `cell.attr('text/text', inboxName)`. The `attr()` method takes a path as the first argument which is the path to the attribute in your `attrs` object. Note that `cell.attr('text/text', 'MY VALUE')` is equivalent to `cell.prop('attrs/text/text', 'MY VALUE')`.

`cell.set()` can only be used to set top level properties, so you would have to do `cell.set('attrs', { text: { text: 'MY VALUE' } })` but that would override other attributes (like `circle` in your case).

Comment: And of course it worked one more time @dave. Thank you so much!